# Javascript/jQuery Form external OnChange function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, forms, onchange

I think I have the logic of this down I just don't exactly know the proper selectors to accomplish this.

I'm editing a page through the DOM that has already been "created" with a third party .asp script.  Forewarning, I have no access to this .asp script so anything associated with this I can't provide.

I am essentially trying to come up with a way to add a dynamic price updater that scrolls with the page, and changes every time an option with a new price is selected. I have to do this in a hack way because, the problem is I have no access to the value of the "change" on the database.  However, it is listed as part of the string in the dropdown box option, exp: [Add +$1.50].

So here is my understanding of what I need to do. Obviously first is grab the form in the id.  Then loop through the select's and grab the string of the value that is selected and search that string for the money value with a regEx. Then add the value to a total that is displayed in an external div elsewhere. Then this function is called whenever anything on that form is changed so onChange somehow.

Is this right? I don't know exactly how to do that. If I can provide anything else that would help, please let me know. I know a small amount of jQuery and Javascript, so any help or references would be helpful.

-Dan

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at [the .val() function](http://api.jquery.com/val/) in jQuery. You can also use jQuery events to set an onchange handler for the select box:

```
jQuery('input:select').change(function() {
    alert(jQuery(this).val());
});
```

That will select any select inputs on your page and alert the value selected to you (you can store this value to search for the proper additional amounts and manipulate it then).